# Alternatives to Enum.valueOf for a generic that doesn't extend Enum?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have the following code

```
protected <T> T func(Class<T> c) {
    if (c.isEnum()) {
        try {
            return c.cast(Enum.valueOf(c, "string"));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

that IDEA reports the error `Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'java.lang.Class<T>', required: 'java.lang.Class<T>'` on in `valueOf` function. I can avoid this error by specifying `<T extends Enum<T>>` in the function header but the idea is that `T` can be a wide range of types, not just enums. Is it possible to get the code to compile/run without restricting `T`?

Comment: The first argument of `valueOf()` MUST be an enum type.... what behavior are you trying to achieve?  What would `valueOf()` return for a non-enum first argument?  I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @JimGarrison `valueOf` throws an IllegalArgumentException if c is not an enum class, or does not have a constant with that name. Hence, `func` would return null. I agree, though, that it would be interesting to know what a method like this is used for...

Comment: What I don't understand is the desire to subvert the compile-time type safety only to re-impose it at runtime.  To what end?

Comment: @Jim Garrison. there is a check if class is `enum` before calling `valueOf` which guarantees that `valueOf` will always get `enum` class.

Comment: I'm trying to read a string from a file and convert it to a typed variable. T can be a Boolean, Integer, Double, String, BigDecimal, etc. I've removed parts of the function not relevant to the problem.

Comment: I understand now that I gave a misleading title. What I need is an alternative to Enum.valueOf like @Judger's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use `Enum.valueOf()`, instead I used `Class.getEnumConstants()`

```
protected <T> T func(Class<T> c) {
    if (c.isEnum())
        for (T t : c.getEnumConstants())
            if (((Enum<?>) t).name().equals("KG"))
                return t;
    return null;
}
```

This way it compiles without warning, but I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Quick, unpleasant answer (I'm sure there's better ones).

You can always just cast `c` to `Class` before using it in `valueOf`.  So

```
return (T) Enum.valueOf((Class) c, "string");
```

would work; provided you know the only `Enum` class that can be provided has an enum constant named `string`.

Probably some warnings to suppress there too...

Comment: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Enum to T`

Comment: @Jim Garrison https://ideone.com/5d0NEF. Still not trying to say this is a good idea...  But it doesn't give a Type mismatch.